# Data type mismatch in criteria expression in excel vba (ado)

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

***i have pasted the old question ,but it is so unclear .Then ,I make a new thread***

I use ADO to run SQL in excel . There are several old worksheets:
The format are nearly the same (maybe the field name ,data are different )-Then i make the amendments to make sure field names the same in every worksheets.

The worksheet are called :

> 2013,2014,2015

i made a sql statement

```
   SELECT   officer ,sum(mkt),sum(null)...... from [2013$] 'the real sql is too long and other fields are not important so i ignore other fields
```

This statement works in [$2014] ,[$2015]

However , it doesn't work in [$2013].

It prompts out

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Then i test in every fields in [$2013]

i found that the problematic fields are

mkt & non

(I tried to paste the columns of mkt and non of [$2014] onto [$2013] .
The sql statement works in [$2013].)

---

Mkt & Non introduction :

Mkt -it may or may not contain numbers

non- it may or may not contain numbers

For example

- Mkt
- 30
- 5
- 
- 35
- 
- 20

Non is similar to Mkt

---

As the error is

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

I believe that the datatype in [$2013] is inconsistent to other worksheets .

Then i tried to change this 2 column datatype from "common" to "numeric" /"currency"/ "percentage" ... in excel

None of them works

Then i used type(cell) to check the datatype in [$2013] and [$2014] of these columns .

They are same in different tables:
mkt in 2013 , non in 2013 ,mkt in 2014 ,non in 2014 :

1 <- numeric

---

As the data of Non and Mkt in each worksheets are similar and the datatype of null and Mkt are same too (1 - numeric ) , i don't know what is the problem .

I don't know whats the problem exactly ..

## SQL UPDATE

FULL SQL

```
    sSQLSting = "SELECT  officer ,NULL, SUM(IIF( isnumeric(mkt) = true and Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and Outcome= 'C', Totalmin, 0 )/468) as NULL," & _
 " SUM(IIF( isnumeric(Non) = true and Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and Outcome= 'C', Totalmin, 0 )/468) ,NULL AS gg ,NULL As ddfd, " & _
 "IIF(ISNULL(sum(mkt)),0,sum(mkt)),Sum(Non),sum(ICP),(sum(mkt)+Sum(Non)+sum(ICP) ) as total ,NULL,NULL,NULL,count(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' ," & _
 "Totalmin, NULL )),NULL,count(IIF(  Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and  (Outcome ='C' OR Outcome='D'OR Outcome='O') , Totalmin, NULL )),NULL,SUM(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' ,Totalmin, 0 )),NULL,SUM(IIF( Survey='CPI' and Activity='FI' and (Outcome ='C' OR Outcome='D') ,Totalmin, 0 )) From  [2015$]  group by officer "
```

Comment: Please post the entire SQL statement... those fields ARE important, even if you don't think so!  (otherwise, take them out... you should never have more going on in a SQL statement than you require for the task at hand, and the error you're getting is indicative of a problem in the WHERE clause of a JOIN, neither of which we can see, if there is any).  Also, why would you `sum(null)`??

Comment: @ jdl134679 please see my SQL update in content

Comment: ADODB with an Excel database will guess the field types from the first 16 records. So I suspect two things: 1. The empty cells in `mkt` and `non`, you mentioned, are not really empty but contain an empty string `""` probably resulting from a formula. 2. In the sheet `2013`, which causes the error, the empty string cells are in majority in first 16 rows. So text data type is guessed which cannot be `SUM`med. In the other sheets the empty string cells are in minority in first 16 rows. So numeric data type is guessed.

Comment: @Axel Richter YES there is totally empty in those column in 2013 .Hence , i add both 0 into these 2 column, make to become numeric data type . It works . You may answer the question again .I will mark it as a  correct answer

Comment: Hm, no I cannot answer this question because it is totally unclear. You mentioned that `type(cell)` was 1 for all cells. That cannot be true if the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" occurs. Also: "there is totally empty in those column in 2013". That can also not be true since then a different error would occur because of `NULL` result or empty record set.

Comment: @Axel Richter i use `type(cell)` to test the first 16 rows of mkt and non ,they are 1 (numeric ).<-- i dun know why the empty goes to numeric datatype . Secondly ,  "there is totally empty in those column in 2013". <--i mean in first 16 rows of mkt and non ,they are all empty . Hence , i believe in your theory .The first 16 rows determine that field datatype and  consider them as non-numeric datatype .  However ,for point 1 , i dun know why the result is 1 when i use type(cell)

Comment: Really empty cells should not impact the field type guessing. If there are the first 16 rows with totally empty cells, the next 16 will be taken. Thats why excel takes them as type 1. Can you please show the VBA code where you are connecting the Excel in your question? Or show at least the connection string? On the other side: The only thing I can belive is that after the totally empty cells there are `""` instead of empty among the following cells.

Comment: IIRC there are a couple of registry values that influence how the data type is guessed. See [Dick Kusleika's Excel blog](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/06/03/external-data-mixed-data-types/) (I wrote this 12 years ago, hopefully it is still relevant!).

Comment: @onedaywhen: This is all true. But totally empty cells mixed with **either** numeric **or** text content is **not** mixed type in terms of type guessing. Mixed type in those terms is only numeric content mixed with text content.

Comment: @Axel Richter  

Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray

Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String



DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName 
sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

Conn.Open sconnect  sSQLSting = "..." 
    Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQLSting)
    
   j = 6
  
    Do While Not rs.EOF
    
Loop
 

rs.Close

    
    





End Sub

Comment: @Axel Richter i use filter to check whether " " exist .The answer is still no .But i add '0' on the first row that solve the question .